# greatest overlap between pairs in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to calculate the greatest overlap between two fields in excel. My current data structure looks as such:

```
fund company
A    a
B    a
C    a
D    b
A    b
B    b
```

I was thinking of an output similar to the following:

```
fund-pair   countunique companies
A, B        2
A, C        1
A, D        1
D, B        1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into find/match for A, B, a, b, etc.?  You could find the row of the first where each exists, or have a master list where all companies are listed and the funds which they'are part of (column A as names, B as fund A with x, C as fund B with x, etc.).

Comment: To create the output you desire, it will most likely require VBA, what have you tried.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.